# Inheritance in Python: My child class is expecting a different data type than the father class (TypeError)

Tags: python, selenium, inheritance

Im trying to create a class that inherit the arguments of the father class, my code looks like this:

```
class casas24(webdriver.Chrome):
def __init__(self, executable_path='chromedriver', port=0, options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None, chrome_options=None, keep_alive=True):
    super().__init__(options)
```

As you can see, so far I just want to inherit the options argument. This argument receives another class of the same library (Selenium) called ChromeOptions, and of course its type Options.

My problem is that at the moment Im trying to create the new instance called casas24 and I try to pass the argument ChromeOptions as I would do it with the father class, I got error.

Code like this:

```
 from casas24.casas24 import casas24
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")



driver = casas24(options=chrome_options)
```

And the error I got:

```
PS C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\Documents\homy\Extract> & "C:/Users/Nicolás Medrano/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "c:/Users/Nicolás Medrano/Documents/homy/Extract/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\Documents\homy\Extract\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = casas24(options=chrome_options)
  File "c:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\Documents\homy\Extract\casas24\casas24.py", line 18, in __init__
    super().__init__(options)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1360, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 565, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás Medrano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Options
```

If I just do this:

```
class casas24(webdriver.Chrome):
    pass
```

It works... I ran out of ideas!

THANKS!

Comment: The `options` argument is not the first one expected by the initializer of `webdriver.Chrome`. Try replacing the current call with `super().__init__(options=options)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Nir H! That was it.